# Exclude record from SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query

```
select * from tblSchool where schoolid=274988 and schooltype not in (2,5)
```

which is working fine.

but I need to exclude those records whose `aType` is 'X' and asubtype is 'Z' at the same time. Like

```
select * from tblSchool where schoolid=274988 and schooltype not in (2,5)
EXCEPT
select * from tblSchool where aType='X' and asubtype = 'Z'
```

Can I do this without except, I mean in a single where?

Comment: You just need to add the condition of the 2nd query to the 1st and you should get what is desired.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add the predicates to the first select like this:

```
select *
from tblSchool
where schoolid = 274988
    and schooltype not in (2, 5)
    and not (
        aType = 'X'
        and asubtype = 'Z'
        )
```

Comment: @GurV, why not just use a simple `NOT (cond1 and cond2)` expression?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a subquery, like:

```
select * from tblSchool 
where schoolid=274988 
and schooltype not in (2,5)
and schoolid not in (select schoolid from tblSchool where aType='X' and asubtype = 'Z')
```

Comment: Is it faster than my query if records are less than 300?

Answer (score 0):

Just use NOT and braces to group the 2 exclusion criteria:

```
SELECT *
FROM tblSchool
WHERE schoolid = 274988
AND schooltype NOT IN (2, 5)
AND NOT (aType = 'X' and asubtype = 'Z')
```